# Sync SharePoint 2010 UPS to a csv file

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync, sync, csv

I get a nightly update of all users' profile properties via csv.  I would like to setup the User Profile Service App to sync to that CSV.  I assume this shouldn't be terribly difficult and has likely been done before.  However my Google-Fu is not up to snuff and I cannot find any good examples.  I have found some [examples using PowerShell](http://iedaddy.com/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-updating-user-profile-properties-with-powershell/) but I thought that using BCS and sync might be a better idea.  Could someone please help me find an example of doing this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use PowerShell. But, if you really must use BCS, look at the samples for creating a custom BSC Connector to XML, XLS, or CSV. There are several out there. Scot Hillier wrote the book and there are samples in there: [http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Business-Connectivity-Services-SharePoint/dp/047061790X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047061790X)

Once you have the BCS connection working you then create a secondary sync connection in the UPA for your BCS import and identify the key, like email or username.

Note, you will still need an LDAP source for initially creating users.

Comment: What are the advantages of PowerShell over BCS?

Comment: Mostly, IMO, simplicity. Adding BCS adds a layer of complexity that may not be required. You can still schedule the job.